# How do I move a picture along a curved path in KDEnlive?

Tags: kdenlive, motion-graphics

It's been a week since I ventured into learning video editing.  I preferred to use KDEnlive because it is open surce software.

My question is the following.  How to make the letter "b" move smoothly from the position x=900 and y=465 to the position x=1680 and y=465 following the blue trace in the picture below?

Comments. The blue line is the upper part of an ellipse with extremities at
x=900 / y=465 and x=1680 / y=465.

I was able to make the letter "b" move from x=900 / y=465 to x=1680 / y=465 in three rectilinear movements.  Red trace of the figure.

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the options for transform are not showing in the sub-window of your screenshot, probably because it is not horizontally wide enough. Try to enlarge the width of that sub-window, and then you will see the additional options appear. In a pull-down menu, select the Smooth option for keyframe interpolation rather than Linear. Then, with maybe a couple additional keyframes along the ellipse, the motion should track the ellipse pretty well.